# how to get the equal records in orderby rand with limit of 6?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am using facing one problem in sql query
Here is my query:-

```
$query = 'SELECT 
          products.id, products.ProductName, products.smallimage as proSmallImage  
          FROM 
          products 
          LEFT JOIN 
          productscolors 
          ON 
          productscolors.proid =products.id  
          WHERE 
          products.id!="'.$productId.'" 
          AND
          products.Enable="YES" 
          AND 
          products.undercatid in("22","16") 
          GROUP BY 
          productscolors.proid 
          ORDER BY 
          rand() limit 0,6';
```

This query executes fine for me but there is one problem i faced is that

You see this in query

```
products.undercatid in("22","16") group by productscolors.proid order by rand() limit 0,6
```

this will return random data where undercatid in 22 and 16 
but i want 3 records from 22 id and 3 records from 16 id 
My current query gives random data from both queries ie.(sometime it gives 5 from 22 undercatid and 1 from 16 undercatid  etc)
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem .
I want 3-3 records from both the undercatid

Comment: Idea is use UNION,  products.undercatid = 22 and limit 0,3 UNION products.undercatid = 16 and limit 0,3

Comment: okay can you write full updated query how it will looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an union of single select

```
select * from ( 
  SELECT  products.id, products.ProductName, products.smallimage as 
  proSmallImage  FROM products  LEFT JOIN productscolors ON 
  productscolors.proid =products.id  where products.id!="'.$productId.'" and 
  products.Enable="YES" and products.undercatid = "22"
  group by productscolors.proid order by rand() 
  limit 0,3
 ) t1 
union all
select * from (
  SELECT  products.id, products.ProductName, products.smallimage as 
  proSmallImage  FROM products  LEFT JOIN productscolors ON 
  productscolors.proid =products.id  where products.id!="'.$productId.'" and 
  products.Enable="YES" and products.undercatid = "16"
  group by productscolors.proid order by rand() 
  limit 0,3 
) t2
```

Comment: @kunal   what mean not working  ... you have an error ? show me .. You have worng result  ? .. explain better please

Comment: thank you bro its working i have doing syntax mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  products.id, products.ProductName, products.smallimage as proSmallImage  FROM products  where products.undercatid in("22") limit 0,3 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  products.id, products.ProductName, products.smallimage as proSmallImage  FROM products where products.undercatid in("16")  limit 0,3 
    LEFT JOIN productscolors ON productscolors.proid =products.id  
    where products.id!="'.$productId.'" and products.Enable="YES" 
    group by productscolors.proid 
    order by rand()
```